# What happens at VACUUM with delta tables?

Tags: delta-lake

When we run `VACUUM` command, does it go through each parquet file and remove older versions of each record or does it retain all the parquet files even id it has one record with the latest version? What about compaction? Is this any different?

Answer (score 1):

Vacuum and Compaction go through the `_delta_log/` folder in your Delta Lake Table and identify the files that are still being referenced.

Vacuum deletes all unreferenced files.
Compaction reads in the referenced files and writes your new partitions back to the table, unreferencing the existing files.

Comment: so does compaction only read the latest version of each record in the referenced files and write into the new partitions?

Comment: I am not a 100% sure if compaction also vacuums, meaning it only compacts referenced files. But I would assume so. Otherwise just vacuum and compact afterwards.

Comment: I wanted to understand what happens when we run vacuum.
lets there are 5 records in one file after inital run in the parquet file. 
in the second run, record 1 is updated and some new records are added and new parquet is created. (now we have 2 parquet files)
AFter this when we run the vacuum, will record 1 be deleted from the inital parquet file or will we still have it as the inital parquet wont't be deleted as it is having latest version of some records.

Comment: It will delete the first parquet. If one record needs to be updated, the whole parquet file gets rewritten with the updated record.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a single version of a Delta Lake table as a set of parquet data files. Every version adds an entry (about files added and removed) to the transaction log (under `_delta_log` directory).

### VACUUM

`VACUUM` allows defining what number of hours to retain (using `RETAIN number HOURS` clause). That gives Delta Lake the versions to delete (up to the `number HOURS`). These versions are "translated" into a series of parquet files (remember one single parquet file belongs to a single version until it is deleted that may take a couple of versions).

This translation gives the files to be deleted.

### Compaction

Compaction is basically an optimization (and is usually triggered by `OPTIMIZE` command or a combination of `repartition`, `dataChange` disabled and `overwrite`).

This is nothing else as another version of a delta table (but this time data is not changed so other transactions can happily be all committed).

The explanation about VACUUM above applies here.

Comment: can you confirm whether the loaded df from `spark.read.format("delta")` would be unchanged after running `.vacuum()`? `.vacuum()` would rather not allow to roll-back to a previous version of the data older than `number HOURS`, correct?

Comment: Cannot confirm. `spark.read.format` is a description of your input data point in a DAG. No data is involved at this step. `vacuum` is transactional and will change what you see next time you run `spark.read.format`

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in my question. I now understand the vacuum command better - it simply removes older parquet files that are not required when reading in the current version of the table.